# Why is my react project crashing when updating from react-scripts 3.2.0 to 3.3.0?

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I updated my react project using

> npm install --save --save-exact react-scripts@3.3.0

But when I start my react project I get this...

> Starting the development server...
>
> <--- Last few GCs --->
>
> > [27403:0x108000000]    53085 ms: Scavenge 2041.3 (2049.1) -> 2040.6 (2049.4) MB, 7.8 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.242, current mu = 0.164)
> >     allocation failure  [27403:0x108000000]    53094 ms: Scavenge 2041.8
> >     (2049.9) -> 2041.2 (2050.1) MB, 7.7 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.242,
> >     current mu = 0.164) allocation failure  [27403:0x108000000]    53101
> >     ms: Scavenge 2042.0 (2050.1) -> 2041.3 (2050.6) MB, 5.2 / 0.0 ms 
> >     (average mu = 0.242, current mu = 0.164) allocation failure
>
> <--- JS stacktrace --->
>
> ==== JS stack trace =========================================
>
> ```
> 0: ExitFrame [pc: 0x100930c99]
> 1: StubFrame [pc: 0x1008e42a7] Security context: 0x3d30707408a1 <JSObject>
> 2: SourceMapConsumer_allGeneratedPositionsFor [0x3d307ed12519] [/Users/bob/IdeaProjects/test-client/node_modules/source-map/lib/source-map-consumer.js:~178]
> ```
>
> [pc=0x183302d049b6](this=0x3d30ec3c01a1 ,0x3d303d727d61 )
>       3: /* anonymous */(aka /...
>
> FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation
>   failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
>
> Writing Node.js report to file:
>   report.20200103.163000.27403.0.001.json Node.js report completed  1:
>   0x10007e9b3 node::Abort() [/usr/local/bin/node]  2: 0x10007eb37
>   node::OnFatalError(char const*, char const*) [/usr/local/bin/node]  3:
>   0x100176337 v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(v8::internal::Isolate*, char
>   const*, bool) [/usr/local/bin/node]  4: 0x1001762d3
>   v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(v8::internal::Isolate*, char
>   const*, bool) [/usr/local/bin/node]  5: 0x1002fa485
>   v8::internal::Heap::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(char const*)
>   [/usr/local/bin/node]  6: 0x1002fbb54
>   v8::internal::Heap::RecomputeLimits(v8::internal::GarbageCollector)
>   [/usr/local/bin/node]  7: 0x1002f8a27
>   v8::internal::Heap::PerformGarbageCollection(v8::internal::GarbageCollector,
>   v8::GCCallbackFlags) [/usr/local/bin/node]  8: 0x1002f6a0d
>   v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage(v8::internal::AllocationSpace,
>   v8::internal::GarbageCollectionReason, v8::GCCallbackFlags)
>   [/usr/local/bin/node]  9: 0x100302124
>   v8::internal::Heap::AllocateRawWithLightRetry(int,
>   v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment)
>   [/usr/local/bin/node] 10: 0x10030219f
>   v8::internal::Heap::AllocateRawWithRetryOrFail(int,
>   v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment)
>   [/usr/local/bin/node] 11: 0x1002ced97
>   v8::internal::Factory::NewFillerObject(int, bool,
>   v8::internal::AllocationType) [/usr/local/bin/node] 12: 0x1005f83e5
>   v8::internal::Runtime_AllocateInYoungGeneration(int, unsigned long*,
>   v8::internal::Isolate*) [/usr/local/bin/node] 13: 0x100930c99
>   Builtins_CEntry_Return1_DontSaveFPRegs_ArgvOnStack_NoBuiltinExit
>   [/usr/local/bin/node] 14: 0x1008e42a7 Builtins_KeyedLoadIC_Megamorphic
>   [/usr/local/bin/node] 15: 0x183302d049b6  16: 0x183302b03a05  npm ERR!
>   code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 1 npm ERR! dms-test-clientnp@0.1.0
>   start: `react-scripts start` npm ERR! Exit status 1 npm ERR!  npm ERR!
>   Failed at the dms-test-clientnp@0.1.0 start script. npm ERR! This is
>   probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging
>   output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
>   /Users/bob/.npm/_logs/2020-01-03T21_30_01_170Z-debug.log ```

Why is this happening?

Comment: there's an open issue for it on the create-react-app [repository](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/8096)  on github

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is an issue in the new release. To resolve this, try to allocate more memory. You can do it in two ways:

- Add this below line in the .bash_profile

> export NODE_OPTIONS=--max-old-space-size=8192

- Change the line in package.json to below way:

> > "scripts": {
> >         "start": "react-scripts --expose-gc --max-old-space-size=8192 start",
> >         "build": "react-scripts --expose-gc --max-old-space-size=8192 build", ... ... }

Comment: Just wanted to add a comment and say this worked for me as well. Thanks for this answer!